# Component URL cannot be retrieved. Make sure component controller is correctly registered

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to setup a multi-language (prefix based) in **Kentico v13.0.126**, however, when creating a content page in a different language I get the following error. This error occurs when trying to load the Page Builder within the admin site.

[image: kentico page builder admin error message]

```
    
    Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
    Stack trace:
    at Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc.AbstractComponentUrlRetriever`1.GetUrl(TDefinition component)
    at Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc.ComponentsMetadataBuilder.CreateWidgetMetadata(WidgetDefinition widget)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.ToArray()
    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
    at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.ToList()
    at Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc.ComponentsMetadataBuilder.GetComponentsMetadata(IEnumerable`1 widgets, IEnumerable`1 sections, IEnumerable`1 pageTemplates, IEnumerable`1 conditionTypes)
    at Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc.ComponentsMetadataBuilder.GetAll()
    at Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc.Internal.KenticoComponentsMetadataController.GetAll()
    at lambda_method674(Closure , Object , Object[] )
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

I followed the official documentation and steps to setup the multilanguage in Kentico from here: https://docs.xperience.io/multilingual-websites/setting-up-multilingual-websites.

This is the event url given on the error details:

```
/Kentico.PageBuilder/Metadata/GetAll?editmode=1&instance=741ee77c-5012-4b6f-aee1-b70c4bf32f39&uh=937c985e358eaa162e1170c0b094b876dbc2a820479895bb239744c06390e73b&administrationurl=https%3A%2F%2Fproject-admin.domain.com%2F
```

**Note**: When the site was set to use only one language (English), the pagebuilder never displayed an error when editing on the admin site.The error is happening when switching to another language and try to edit the page using page builder.

Any tip or idea is always welcome!

Thanks in advance